# Generating a random GLfloat value

Tags: haskell

How do I generate a *random* GLfloat value in Haskell?

There is no instance declaration for Random GLfloat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is no instance, make an instance.  That's the first thing they teach you.

There are many ways, but the easiest is probably to generate a type of sufficient resolution then cast that to a GLfloat:

```
instance Random GLfloat where
    random g = 
        let f :: Double
            (f,g2) = random g
        in (fromRational (toRational f), g2)
```

`Double` should suffice seeing as that's a 64 bit floating value while `GLFloat` (which wraps `CFloat`) is a 32 bit float.  `Float` should be sufficient, but I'm not well-versed enough in the specifics of Floating point to know for sure that this is true for all platforms.

Comment: See also `realToFrac`, which is defined as `fromRational.toRational`, but has specializations for common casts, because converting between floats and rationals is fairly expensive.